# UIToolbar alignment problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the interface builder, I can set the alignment for my UIToolbar to be at the bottom of my screen or to be at my top of my screen. How can this be done programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the UIToolBar's frame or center. It's not alignment it's position. Can be done like so:

`[myToolBar setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]; 

//OR  

[myToolBar setCenter: CGPointMake(x, y)];`

If the UIToolBoor is auto aligned in IB, it's because IB is programmed to help you position stuff.

~ Natanavra.

Answer (score 0):

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  //Initialize the toolbar
  toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
  toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

  //Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
  [toolbar sizeToFit];

  //Caclulate the height of the toolbar
  CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

  //Get the bounds of the parent view
  CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

  //Get the height of the parent view.
  CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

  //Get the width of the parent view,
  CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

  //Create a rectangle for the toolbar
  CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

  //Reposition and resize the receiver
  [toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

  //Create a button
  UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];

  [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];

  //Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

[[self tableView] reloadData];

}

- (void) info_clicked:(id)sender {

  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [toolbar removeFromSuperview];

  }